# Python data frame column string extraction efficient way?

Tags: python, pandas, pattern-matching, dataframe

I have a data frame df with column ID in the following pattern. What I want is to return a string column with the number after the dash sign. For the example below, I need 01,01,02. I used the command below and it failed. Since it is a very large data frame, I think it might be inefficient to do a loop and row by row extraction. Please advise, thanks

df['ID'].apply(lambda x: x.split('-')[1], axis=1)

error: () got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

```
DP00010-01
DP00020-01
..........
DP00010-02
```

Update: Edchum's solution

```
df['ID'].str.split('-').str[1]
```

works for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use vectorised [`str`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#string-handling) method [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas.Series.str.split) if you have a recent version of pandas:

```
In [26]:
df['val'].str.split('-').str[1]
Out[26]:
0    01
1    01
2    02
dtype: object
```

If the dash position was fixed then you could slice it

```
In [28]:    
df['val'].str[8:]
Out[28]:
0    01
1    01
2    02
Name: val, dtype: object
```

As to why your method failed, you were calling `apply` on a Series (`df['ID']` is a Series and not a df) and there is no [`axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas.Series.apply) param so the following works:

```
In [29]:
df['val'].apply(lambda x: x.split('-')[1])

Out[29]:
0    01
1    01
2    02
Name: val, dtype: object
```

Comment: I need the numbers after the "-" and the position of "-" is not fixed. I can't use fixed position to slice it.